# Creating raster from polyline with the exact same resolution/extent as another raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I'm trying to create a raster layer from a polyline layer (roads) that has the same extent as another raster layer (DEM)

What I've done so far is convert the second raster layer (DEM) with the extent I want to a polygon. This was then used to clip the polyline layer (roads). The polyline layer was then buffered, and converted into a raster layer with a resolution of 10x10.

However, the extent is different. Due to this, I can't do raster multiplication.

How can I ensure the extent is the same as the 'base' raster layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcMap in the Geoprocessing Menu, click Environments... There is a section called Processing Extent. Set the Snap Raster to be the existing raster layer (DEM). Then, other rasters you create will "line up" with each other and operations like raster multiplication will behave as expected.

[image]

Comment: If I do this, will it ensure that all the rasters conform to the same extent and resolution?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of the Extent and Snap Raster settings. It will apply in that MXD

Comment: sometimes ArcGIS does not make EXACTLY the same extent despite this, but it is very close.

Comment: @Matthew Note that to ensure you get the same resolution for your new raster, you should also specify the cell size in the 'Raster Analysis' section of this same Environment settings menu. See [documentation for the Snap Raster setting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm)